# Триггер меняющий свойство класса

Tags: c#, wpf

Может ли триггер менять свойства класса?

Я имею ввиду не только что то на форме менять, но и внутреннее публичное свойство формы. У меня не получается в сеттере триггера в `Property` вставить биндинг к нужному свойству. (выдает ошибку компиляции)

Приведу пример:

```
<CheckBox>
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" Value="False"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

`Binding` нельзя задать в свойстве `Property` типа `Setter`. `Binding` можно задать только в параметре `DependencyProperty` объекта `DependencyObject`.

Comment: Вам не должно такого хотеться. Похоже, вы решаете какую-то задачу средствами, не предназначенными для этого. Опишите, что вам нужно получить реально, вашу _настоящую_ задачу.

Comment: Все я по другому уже сделал.

Answer (score 1):

Триггеры предназначены в первую очередь для стилизации. Для работы с "внутренней" логикой всё-таки лучше обрабатывать события.